# How to get text from edittext or textview or button using android resource id in appium

Tags: android, appium

I have a requirement where I should get the text from UI elements which change there value dynamically I have python interface written on top of appium to expose the functionality. But now I need to expose new Interface API to get value from Textview/EditText/Button. I just started using Appium. Hence tried googling the question but could not find a proper solution. Thanks if any one update's the same.

Comment: what type of device u trying?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already setup AndroidDriver, this will do the job in **Java**:

```
AndroidElement textView = (AndroidElement) AndroidDriver.findElementById("(resource_id>"); 
System.out.println(textView.getText());
```